# Drop-cap (lettrine) with thmtools

Tags: errors, thmtools, drop-cap

I want to make theorems, definitions, etc. to start with a drop-cap, like on the picture below.

[image]

It is produced with the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \lettrine{D}{efinition.} \lipsum[2]


\end{document}
```

While approach with the `thmtools` gives me an error, when used with `lettrine`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries,
headpunct=.,
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=0.4em
]{DEFINITIONstyle}

\declaretheorem[%
style=DEFINITIONstyle,%
name=\lettrine{D}{efinition}%
]{Definition}


\begin{document}


    \begin{Definition}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{Definition}

\end{document}
```

The error is

```
! Use of \\declaretheorem doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.20 ]{Definition}
```

Also, further there is another error in the console (if you continue the compilation by clicking the `enter`):

```
?
! Argument of \@lettrine has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.20 ]{Definition}
```

If I change `name=\lettrine{D}{efinition}` to `name=Definition`, the file compiles succesfully.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Haha, I thought I had found a solution, but it made the word “definition” disappear altogether. By the way, in 99 % of cases, you don't need those `%` at the end of lines in `<key> = <value>` lists.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it's a horrible hack IMO.

The reasons the OP's attempt didn't work are

1. The `\lettrine` command typesets the initial letter *and then sets up the paragraph shape for typesetting the remainder of the paragraph.* If you put that in the 'name' parameter of `\declaretheoremstyle`, things get done in the wrong place. But apart from that,
2. `\declaretheoremstyle` and `\lettrine` are fighting over using the same temporary LaTeX variables, with names like `\@tempdima`, etc. This is what causes the actual error messages.

The fix is:

1. Modify the `\lettrine` command to save the paragraph shape in a global macro, instead of re-calculating it every time in a local macro. This is horrible, because the `\lettrine` command is a huge monolithic block of code - in fact it's almost all of the `lettrine` package - though only 3 lines need to be changed.
2. Run the `\lettrine` command just once, to set up the typesetting of the word `Definition`, and store the result in a LaTeX box.
3. Change `\declaretheorem` to copy the box containing the work 'definition', and insert the pre-calculated paragraph shape to typeset the text of each different theorem.

Note, the example only works for a single theorem type. If you want several types (Definition, Remark, Lemma, Note, etc) you will need to create a box for each one, and also save the paragraph shapes `\L@parshape` in separate macros.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Modify the \@lettrine command to make L@parshape a global variable.

\makeatletter
\def\@lettrine[#1]#2#3{%
  \setcounter{L@lines}{\value{DefaultLines}}%
  \setcounter{L@depth}{\value{DefaultDepth}}%
  \renewcommand*{\L@hang}{\DefaultLhang}%
  \renewcommand*{\L@oversize}{\DefaultLoversize}%
  \renewcommand*{\L@raise}{\DefaultLraise}%
  \renewcommand*{\L@ante}{}%
  \setlength{\L@Findent}{\DefaultFindent}%
  \setlength{\L@Nindent}{\DefaultNindent}%
  \setlength{\L@slope}{\DefaultSlope}%
  \setlength{\L@novskip}{\DiscardVskip}%
  \ifLettrineImage\L@imagetrue\else\L@imagefalse\fi
  \ifLettrineOnGrid\L@gridtrue\else\L@gridfalse\fi
  \ifLettrineRealHeight\L@realhtrue\else\L@realhfalse\fi
  \setkeys{L}{#1}%
  \sbox{\L@tbox}{\LettrineTextFont{\LettrineSecondString}}%
  \ifL@realh
    \def\@tempa{#3}
    \ifx\@tempa\@empty
      \PackageWarning{lettrine.sty}%
        {Empty second argument,\MessageBreak
         ignoring option `realheight';}%
    \else
      \sbox{\L@tbox}{\LettrineTextFont{#3}}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \if\DefaultOptionsFile\relax
  \else
    \begingroup
    \InputIfFileExists{\DefaultOptionsFile}%
      {}%
      {\PackageWarning{lettrine.sty}%
         {File \DefaultOptionsFile\space not found}%
      }%
    \def\color##1##{\l@color{##1}}%
    \let\l@color\@gobbletwo
    \def\textcolor##1##{\l@textcolor{##1}}%
    \def\l@textcolor##1##2##3{##3}%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname l@#2-keys\endcsname\relax
                  \gdef\l@LOKeys{}%
                \else
                  \xdef\l@LOKeys{\csname l@#2-keys\endcsname}%
                \fi
    \endgroup
    \def\KV@prefix{KV@L@}%
    \let\@tempc\relax
    \expandafter\KV@do\l@LOKeys,\relax,
    \sbox{\L@lbox}{\LettrineFont #2}%
    \setlength{\LettrineWidth}{\wd\L@lbox}%
    \def\KV@prefix{KV@L@}%
    \let\@tempc\relax
    \expandafter\KV@do\l@LOKeys,\relax,
    \setkeys{L}{#1}%
  \fi
  \ifL@image
     \sbox{\L@lbox}{\LettrineFontEPS{#2}}%
  \else
     \sbox{\L@lbox}{\LettrineFont #2}%
  \fi
  \sbox{\L@tbox}{\LettrineTextFont{#3}}%
  \@tempdima=\baselineskip
  \ifnum\value{L@lines}=1
    \setlength{\L@first}{\ht\L@lbox}%
    \addtolength{\L@first}{-\ht\L@tbox}%
    \setlength{\L@lraise}{\z@}%
  \else
    \setlength{\L@first}{-\value{L@lines}\@tempdima}%
    \addtolength{\L@first}{\@tempdima}%
    \sbox{\@tempboxa}{\LettrineTextFont x}%
    \addtolength{\L@first}{-\ht\@tempboxa}%
    \setlength{\L@lraise}{-\L@raise\L@first}%
    \addtolength{\L@first}{\L@lraise}%
    \addtolength{\L@first}{\ht\L@lbox}%
    \addtolength{\L@lraise}{-\value{L@lines}\@tempdima}%
    \addtolength{\L@lraise}{\@tempdima}%
  \fi
  \par
  \ifdim\L@first>\L@novskip
    \ifL@grid
      \@tempdima=\baselineskip
      \@tempdimb=\@tempdima
      \advance\@tempdimb by \L@novskip
      \@tempcnta=1
      \loop\ifdim\L@first>\@tempdimb
         \advance\@tempcnta by 1
         \advance\L@first by -\@tempdima
      \repeat
      \vskip\@tempcnta\baselineskip
    \else
      \vskip\L@first
    \fi
  \fi
  \setlength{\L@Pindent}{\wd\L@lbox}%
  \addtolength{\L@Pindent}{-\L@hang\wd\L@lbox}%
  \settowidth{\L@first}{\L@ante}%
  \addtolength{\L@Pindent}{\L@first}%
  \addtolength{\L@Pindent}{\L@Findent}%
  \setlength{\L@first}{\linewidth}%
  \addtolength{\L@first}{-\L@Pindent}%
  \addtolength{\L@Nindent}{\L@Pindent}%
  \setlength{\L@next}{\linewidth}%
  \addtolength{\L@next}{-\L@Nindent}%
  \addtolength{\L@Pindent}{\rightmargin}%
  \addtolength{\L@Nindent}{\rightmargin}%
  \setlength{\LettrineWidth}{\wd\L@lbox}%
  \setlength{\LettrineHeight}{\ht\L@lbox}%
  \setlength{\LettrineDepth}{\dp\L@lbox}%
  \addtocounter{L@lines}{1}%
  \addtocounter{L@lines}{\value{L@depth}}%
  \gdef\L@parshape{\c@L@lines \the\L@Pindent \the\L@first}% CHANGED
  \@tempcnta=\tw@
  \@whilenum \@tempcnta<\c@L@lines\do{%
     \global\edef\L@parshape{\L@parshape \the\L@Nindent \the\L@next}% CHANGED
     \addtolength{\L@Nindent}{\L@slope}%
     \addtolength{\L@next}{-\L@slope}%
     \advance\@tempcnta\@ne}%
  \global\edef\L@parshape{\L@parshape \rightmargin \the\linewidth}% CHANGED
  \noindent
  \parshape=\L@parshape\relax
  \smash{\llap{\mbox{\L@ante}\raisebox{\L@lraise}{\usebox{\L@lbox}}%
         \hskip \the\L@Findent}}%
  \usebox{\L@tbox}%
}

% Run the lettrine command once, save the result in a box, and set up \L@parshape

\newbox\lettrinebox
\setbox\lettrinebox\hbox{\lettrine{D}{efinition}}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries,
headpunct=.,
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=0.4em
]{DEFINITIONstyle}

% 'name' parameter copies the saved box.
% 'postheadhook' inserts the parshape created by lettrine.

\declaretheorem[%
style=DEFINITIONstyle,%
name=\copy\lettrinebox,
postheadhook={\parshape=\L@parshape\relax}%
]{Definition}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{Definition}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{Definition}

    \begin{Definition}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{Definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, though I hope there is a simplier solution.

Comment: A "simpler solution" would be to completely rewrite the `lettrine` package in a more modular style - but I'm not going to spend time doing that!